# Django shows 404 error on media files when debug = False in production

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, sorl-thumbnail

I'm trying to put a django website live and after going through the deployment checklist and turning `debug = False` django gives out a 404 error and only static files are loaded no media files uploaded from users are displayed. However with `debug=True` all the images and files work properly. below are the configurations of the project with `debug = True`. The console logs show multiple missing files.can someone point to me what i'm doing wrong?

settings.py
[image]

urls.py
[image]

console errors
[image]

Comment: Have you set your web server to serve media files? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are putting the application in `DEBUG=False` "mode", this means that django won't serve any static files. But on the other hand, if you want to test locally how `DEBUG=False` affects your environment, locally you can use `python manage.py runserver --insecure` option which will allow django to serve static files. But I must note that this is vastly inefficient and maybe insecure too.

Hope this helps.